# Scraping Specific Tables using Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

What should i do to get only specific tables which are having a heading such as "Specifications" or "Product Details".The Url has many tables and i want to scrape only the table having the above details.the link is:(http://catalog.koffler.com/item/ieee-841-motors/ge-x-d-ultra-841-tefc-extra-severe-duty-motors/M352)
and here is my code in xpath:

```
units=response.xpath('//table//text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

The site is a bit ugly (it's use tables for presentation) but you can get any value you want using this way (you'll need to `split()` below values later ):

```
Voltage = response.xpath('string(//td[ ./div/span/h2[.="Voltage"] ]/following-sibling::td[2])').extract_first()
PriceSymbol= response.xpath('string(//td[ ./div/span/h2[.="Price Symbol"] ]/following-sibling::td[2])').extract_first()
```